# Is there a standard/recommended directory structure for Debian packages?

Tags: python, debian, packaging

My next project will be a Debian daemon written in Python and I want to package it as a Debian native package. The project is versioned using Git and the code is hosted in GitHub.

How can I organize directories and branches in the repository? Is there a standard/common/recommended way?

The project is basically composed by some python scripts and systemd unit files. By looking around I came up with this directory structure but I don't know if it is reasonable:

```
my-app/
├── debian/
│   ├── control
│   ├── copyright
│   ├── changelog
│   ├── rules
│   └── ...
├── my_module/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_script.py
│   └── ...
├── systemd/
│   ├── my-service.service
│   └── ...
├── README.md
├── LICENSE
└── ...
```

Comment: There is no standard way. It is recommended not to include `debian/` because this will confuse things (it can be used only by one distribution/version). My recommendation: look at a similar good package, and copy their structure

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi i think this is not exaxctly true. the reason why `debian/` should not included is, that upstream developers are often sloppy packagers and don't follow the Debian packaging guidelines. if somebody (else) wants to create a *proper Debian package* (that is included in the Debian distributions), these packaging attempts are usually just a nuisance.

Comment: @umläute: sloppy is not the only reason: we have different policies for different distribution (versions), so we may use different dependencies. But also different rules, and this question touch one sensitive topic: deamon (how to start it, if and how setting default [some distribution are "default safe: so do not start, do no listen"], about log managing, about setting firewall rules, ...). It is not much a nuisance for distributions: packaging tools will discard `debian/`, but for power users which are confused about where is the real `debian/` data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are asking about the **directory structure** (which files should be where), not the **repository structure** (which would be about branches).

the structure is as follows:

- the upstream project (e.g. the content of a source release tarball)
- PLUS a `debian/` folder in the root of this directory

that's it.
this structure was designed to allow packaging of arbitrary projects - with the only constraint that there is no `debian/` folder.

now, this structure is very tightly coupled to the concept of having upstream-development separate from Debian-packaging. (something which might not apply to your use case, as you seem to be both upstream developer and the one creating the Debian package).

in order to make life easier for an eventual adaption into Debian proper (e.g. adaption of the package into a real Debian release), you should make sure that the `/debian` directory is not included in the release tarballs.

You should also exclude repository configuration files from your release tarballs (`.gitignore` files, CI-configuration,...)

if using git, you might add a `.gitattributes` file that contains (among other things):

```
/debian/    export-ignore
.git*       export-ignore
```

There's also a more elaborate online guide on how to be a nice upstream for Debian: https://wiki.debian.org/UpstreamGuide